# D3 Directed graphs

Tags: d3.js, directed-graph

I have used the following example to generate directed graphs

http://bl.ocks.org/1153292

I want to add a click event so that when the user clicks on a node, the heading of the node is displayed

So far i did this

```
var circle = svg.append("svg:g").selectAll("circle")
    .data(force.nodes())
  .enter().append("svg:circle")
    .attr("r", 6)
    **.on("mouseup", disp)**
    .call(force.drag);
     ;

function disp() {
    alert("Display the heading of the node clicked here");

};
```

Please advise me how to display that

Comment: What do you mean by "heading" here? The title? Or something about the node angle or orientation?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `.on()` in order to have a click event

```
circle.on("click", function(d) {
    alert(d.name)
})
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/chrisJamesC/HgHqy/