# Make interactive Page in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to create a user friendly interactive page in Javascript. The purpose of the page is 
**Taking a connected graph as input and perform various operations on it** 
The method of input should be something like we make in theory on our notebook(with circles and lines connecting them). 
Actually I am a bit confused where do I start.
What I have thought before is:
1. Create a circular `div` using jQuery when a user clicks a specific button( with unique `id` ).
2. Make that `div` draggable and droppable.
3. Connect the two div using a line.

I am stuck here, the 3rd point. How do I connect two div elements that are spread out in space using a line and also take the distance between them as input from user?
I want to store the distances using an array.

Any help how do I do that? I know JavaScript and jQuery. 
Any references or guidance or further reading sources will also be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [D3.js](http://d3js.org/) , a JavaScript library.

It sounds like D3 will fit your needs perfectly. It's as easy to learn as jQuery.

D3 is centered around array manipulation, which sound like what you are looking for.

Specifically, the [D3 Force Layout API](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout) may be what you are most interested in.

Comment: see also:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10913407/d3-directed-graphs and http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1153292